# How can I improve my Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out if what I'm doing is the right way. I have a comment form and when it gets clicked I'm appending the comment into a div element through Ajax. When the page is refreshed then of course that would disappear and instead of it I have a foreach loop that runs and echos the comments. Since they both have the same CSS attributes they look the same to the user. The reason I'm doing it this way is because the foreach loop gets updated only after a refresh. Is there a better way? Can I update the page directly from the database without refresh? I basically need that every time a user clicks on the comment button that the foreach loop will run again but I couldn't find how to do it. I feel like I'm covering a gun shot with bandage the way I do it at the moment.

Loop:

```
@foreach($comment as $comments)
 @if($comments->image_id == $image->id)
  <div id="{{$comments->id}}" class="col-md-5 ajaxrules">
  <div class="deletecomment">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2"> 
    <img src="{{$comments->user_avatar}}" class="img-circle buddy">
  </div>
  <div class="hello col-md-10"> 
    <h4>{!! $image->user_name !!}</h4>
    <p class="left">{!!$comments->body!!} </p>
  </div> 
  </div>
 @endif
@endforeach 

//Where I append the comments through Ajax until the refresh that replaces it with the loop

<div class="man">

</div>
```

Ajax:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.send-form').click(function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
       var username = "{{ $username }}";
       var one = $('textarea[id="{{$image->id}}"]').val();
       var value = "{{$image->id}}";

       var begin = '<div class="col-md-5 addavatar">'+'<div class="deletecomment">'+'<i class="fa fa-trash-o">'+'</i>'+'</div>'+'<div class="col-md-2">'+'<img src="{{$profile}}" class="img-circle">'+'</div>'+'<div class="hello col-md-10">'+'<h4>' + username +'</h4>'+'<p>'+one+'</p>'+'</div>'+'</div>';

     if(one.length > 0){
       console.log(username);
       $('textarea[id="{{$image->id}}"]').val('');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'comment',
      type: "post",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
        if (token) {
              return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
        }                
    }, 
    data: {'id': value, 'comment': one},
    success:function(data){
        $( ".man" ).append([begin]);
    },error:function(){ 
        console.log("error!!!!");
    } 
   });
  }      
 });  
});

 </script>
```

Comment: When user press comment button you have to save the comment in your database through ajax and then update page with JQuery SlideDown function. I'm sure that this tutorial is going to get
your answer http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/

Comment: No need to resort to using a framework to make this happen... I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but if you want to load comments without refreshing the page then you can create a PHP script that grabs the comment data from your database (or wherever you store it) and outputs it for an AJAX call that you create. Basically your JS calls the server-side script whenever you want to update the comments and then updates the DOM. Another way to create DOM nodes in jQuery is like this: `var $element = $('<div class="my-class" />')`. And then you can use methods like `append()` to add structure.

Comment: The comment is being saved to the database, that's not the problem. The problem is after the foreach loop finishes to run any new comment won't be echoed, so that's why I added that extra div, but that's not a perfect solution. I need a way to rerun the foreach loop on each comment click

Comment: If you want the output from your `foreach` loop then place that logic in the script you are requesting with your AJAX and output the HTML (or data if you want to build the HTML in JS). Inside your `success` callback you have access to the response from the serve-side script, which could be the HTML that you add to the DOM. I'm honestly not sure if that answers your question as it is worded awkwardly...

Answer (score 0):

You are killing yourself. 
Manipulate the DOM via javascript code like you do it's really hard work! 
You are not suppose to write html inside javascript strings, there must be another way!

And there is... Welcome to AngularJS! 
In angular you can write your html and assign a javascript controller to it, perform ajax request and after the ajax complete you can bind the returned data to the html automatically! That means the angular refresh your html and do all the work for you. Even perform loop of let's say, row in a table, etc...

Comment: Angular is hard. I just need a way to refresh the foreach loop on every comment click and that will do the job. Is there an easier way to achieve this besides angular?